# How to toggle between two int values in edit text type of structure

Tags: android

I have only two int values and i want any one two select at a time.And i am not able to find the solution.We use dropbox in C# for this purpose.What is the substitute of it in android.

Comment: If you mean screen control it must be Spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android ,you can use the [Spinner widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html), something like a dropBox.

For a two-state selection, you can use the [ToggleButton widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).

Comment: Missing links in this post:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 0):

For  two-state selection, ToggleButton will be the best choice.If want to choose from more then two then use spinner with radiobutton.